# How can I change the color of a textbox based on the cell value in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, textbox, backcolor

On my userform, I have a "next" button which loops through a worksheet.  If cell in column CL = "yes", then change color of textbox10 to Yellow, otherwise leave it white.  Problem is, it will only change to yellow if I don't have an "Else" statement, and  then it won't turn back to white.

I've tried changing Private Sub TextBox10_Change() to Private Sub TextBox10_Enter() and then also added a ...Textbox10_Exit() but still the same results.

```
Private Sub TextBox10_change()

Dim i As Integer

Dim Lastrow As Integer

Lastrow = Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Lastrow

If ActiveSheet.Range("CL" & i) = "yes" Then
    Me.TextBox10.BackColor = vbYellow
Else
    Me.TextBox10.BackColor = vbWhite
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Basically, nothing happens unless I remove:

```
Else

  Me.Textbox10.BackColor = vbWhite
```

and even then it turns yellow but never turns back to white.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work, but it will be matched to whatever is in the last row (ie yellow if the last row is "yes").

If you want it to be yellow if any of the values are "yes" and white if none are "yes" then

```
Me.TextBox10.BackColor = vbWhite
For i = 2 To Lastrow
    If ActiveSheet.Range("CL" & i) = "yes" Then
        Me.TextBox10.BackColor = vbYellow    
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Tried it, but I'm having the same problem...once yellow, stays yellow.

Comment: Do _any_ of the cells in column CL have the word "yes" in them?  If so, the box will be yellow.  If this is not what you are after you will have to describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, some cells in CL have "yes" and depending on the code I mentioned above, it will change to yellow for the first one it finds, but then it stays yellow from that point on whether it has "yes" or not.

Comment: So what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: turn yellow when it finds yes, turn white when it is blank.

Comment: But you are looping through a number of rows.  In your original code it will keep changing colour and end up with the colour matching what is on the last row.  Are you expecting it to flash between yellow and white?

Comment: When it changes the text in the textbox, it is on a specific row.  I would like it to color the textbox based on what is in column CL of that row.  if the row does not have the word "yes" in CL of that row, I don't want it to have a color.  what the previous row shows shouldn't reflect anything as I advance through the loop.  Or at least that's my intent.

Comment: In that case you don't want the For Next at all!  You need a variable that represents whichever row you are on and just look at the value on that row.  How does the form know which row you are looking at?

Answer (score 0):

The way it is written, it will only display a color change for the textbox, based on the value of CL in the last row, Did you want for it to cycle through one row at a time?

Comment: You can see that from the behaviour when you remove the else statement. It changes to yellow the first time it meets the condition, and never changes back since there is no statement telling it to.

Comment: Yes, I would like it to cycle one row at a time.  But as I click the "next" button, it does cycle one row at a time.  but it doesn't update the color based on what's in CL of that row.

Comment: Do you have one text box or multiple text boxes?

Comment: If its that you have a different text box for every row, then your code needs to increment the text box name as well when you loop through the rows

Comment: I have 23 textboxes in the userform.  I have different textboxes for columns, not different textboxes for every row.

Comment: OK.  In that case you need to set the TextBoxes individually.  You keep changing the same one.